# Hiding datagridviews bug

Tags: c#, user-interface, radio-button

I have a windows form with a panel on the left, which consists purely of radiobuttons, and a tabcontrol in the middle, with multiple tab pages within it. Each of these individual tabpages have a series of datagridviews within it, which are shown and hidden depending on which radio button you check.

I accomplish this effect by having each of the radiobuttons on the left assigned a CheckChanged event, which loops through all of the controls within the tabpagecontrol.SelectedTab, and calls .Show() on the corresponding datagridview and calls **.Hide() on the rest** so that only one datagridview is visible at one time.

My problem occurs when i try to programmatically check one of these RadioButtons. Lets say in Method X, I write RadioButtonA.checked = true. This triggers the usual CheckedChange event handling, which loops through all the datagridviews on the currently selected tabpage and calls .Hide() on everything except the one datagridview form that the radiobutton is supposed to bring up and calls .Show() instead. However, on one of these .Hide() calls on the datagridview, it ends up triggering the RadioButtonA.CheckedChange event **AGAIN** for a second time. When i look at the sender argument passed to the function, it shows that the sender is the RadioButton i just programmatically clicked on.

I am adding these datagridviews programmatically and can confirm that there are no eventhandlers assigned whatsoever to them. Can anyone help me determine what is causing this additional event to get triggered? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For obnoxious change events that trickle through and upset other event handlers on my forms, I've found the only solution is to add a small boolean value:

```
bool radioIng;

void MyMethod() {
  radioIng = true;
  try {
    radioButton1.Checked = true;
    // etc.
  } finally {
    radioIng = false;
  }
}

void radioButton_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (radioIng) return;
  // rest of code here
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alternately, you could just remove all of your event handlers and reconnect them later:

```
void MyMethod() {
  try {
    radioButton1.CheckChanged -= radioButton_EventHandler;
    radioButton2.CheckChanged -= radioButton_EventHandler;
    radioButton3.CheckChanged -= radioButton_EventHandler;
    // execute your code
    radioButton1.Checked = true;
  } finally {
    radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_EventHandler);
    radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_EventHandler);
    radioButton3.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_EventHandler);
  }
}

void radioButton_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (sender == radioButton1) {
    // code here to handle
  } else if (sender == radioButton2) {
    // code here to handle
  } else if (sender == radioButton3) {
    // code here to handle
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jp2code for your suggestion, but it seems that this treats the symptom rather than the cause. If possible, I would like to resolve the underlying issue and resort to this approach as last resort. Thanks.

Comment: Edited with a more correct technique that addresses the underlying issue. :) The `Boolean` solution is just as effective ...and faster!